# Puppeteer iterating through elementHandles from page.$$ selector

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm building a scraper, however I'm stuck at iterating through the elementHandles.

I need to get the list of row elements which I do successfully. After that for each row I need to capture tds text/innerHTML (unsure which is which). For now it would be great just to print them out in stdout.

The error I'm getting is `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: tds.forEach is not a function`, which from my googling around tells me that tds is not an array.

I am able to achieve this in python and selenium, but since I'm a javascript newbie, I anticipate I'm doing something very wrong.

From my understanding `element.$$('td')` returns a Promise, but if I put await I get the `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

```
  const selectors = await page.$$('#transactionItems > tbody > tr');
  console.log(selectors.length); // outputs 31 which is the right number
  selectors.forEach( (element) => {
    let tds = element.$$('td');
    console.log(tds);
    tds.forEach( (element) => { 
      console.log(element.innerText)
    });
  });
```

EDIT:

I have tried the following code which prints it successfully, but that's still not what I'd want.

```
const selectors = await page.$$('#transactionItems > tbody > tr ');
console.log(selectors.length);
for(let tr of selectors){
  const trText = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, tr);
  console.log(trText)
}
```

it outputs the following:

```
<td> T737410C - <a class="pointer" target="_blank" onclick="openAPRImageWindow(&quot;T071835642571&quot;,&quot;112255603963&quot;);">Image</a></td>
<td>02/05/2018 06:48:06</td>
<td>DRPA</td>
<td> 07W - CBB</td>
<td>OPEN</td>
<td>$5.00</td>
<td>$25.00</td>
<td>$0.00</td>
<td>$30.00</td>
```

What I would ideally need the output to be is
`['T737410C', '02/05/2018 06:48:06', 'OPEN', '5.00', '25.00']`

Comment: If you just want the text content (and no HTML tags), use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: @tony19 this will not work as the word ` - image` will be left in

Comment: @Rippo Yes, that's why I said **"if you just want the text content"**. Further text parsing is implied.

Comment: Depends on what is contained in each `a href` as if is just the word image, simple, if not then it may be impossible. But `yes` you can use `innerText`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this script:-

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr><td> T737410C - <a href=".">Image</a></td>
        <td>02/05/2018 06:48:06</td><td>DRPA</td>
        <td> 07W - CBB</td><td>OPEN</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tr td'))
      return tds.map(td => {
         var txt = td.innerHTML;
         return txt.replace(/<a [^>]+>[^<]*<\/a>/g, '').trim();
      });
  });

  //You will now have an array of strings
  console.log(data);
  await browser.close();
})()
```

However it is worth mentioning that you may need to do some extra replaces to remove the trailing dashes etc.

Outputs

[image]

Comment: You could just use `innerText` to avoid having to parse the HTML tags.

Comment: As @tony19 points out you can use innerText if you know the TD's will only contain <a href..>Image</a>

Comment: @Rippo So what is the takeaway here? Are you not suppose to use page.$$(selector) to iterate through the elements?

Comment: "ReferenceError: document is not defined"